# torch tensor reshape from torch.Size([1, 16384, 3]) to torch.Size([1, 128, 128, 3])

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a torch tensor shaped, torch.Size([1, 16384, 3]) and I want it to be torch.Size([1, 128, 128, 3]).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .view method, but make sure you don't truncate or extropolate dimension as you will get a Runtime Error.

I suggest:

```
# Your tensor
a = torch.ones((1, 16384, 3))
a = a.view((1, 128, 128, 3))

# Test if it works
print(a.size())
>> torch.Size([1, 128, 128, 3])
```

Optional: Also you can used up to 1 inferred size value like this

```
a = torch.ones((1, 16384, 3))
# Place -1 wherever you want an inferred value but make sure only one -1. 
a = a.view(1, -1, 128, 3))

# or 

a = a.view(1, 128, 128, -1))
```

Sarthak Jain

Comment: Wonderful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new fish, and maybe you can choose "view()" method in Pytorch.
Like:

```
variable.view(128,128)
```

then done.

Comment: I believe that will cast an error `RuntimeError: shape '[128, 128]' is invalid for input of size 49152` becuase 128 * 128 != 16384 * 3